# Why isn't my Exclusion showing up?

Tags: untagged

This plot is Indeterminate at x==0:

```
siney = Plot[Sin[x]/x, {x, -5 \[Pi], 5 \[Pi]}, 
  PlotRange -> {{- 5 \[Pi], 5 \[Pi]}, {-1, 1}}, Frame -> True, 
  Exclusions -> x == 0, ExclusionsStyle -> Red]
```

So why an I not getting a red vertical at that point?

Comment: `Limit[Sin[x]/x, x -> 0]` gives `1`. Could you please draw what graphical output you are expecting?

Comment: It is there, it is just too small to see easily. Use `Plot[Sin[x]/x, {x, -5 Pi, 5 Pi}, PlotRange -> {{-5 Pi, 5 Pi}, {-1, 1.1}}, Frame -> True, Exclusions -> x == 0, ExclusionsStyle -> Directive[Red, AbsoluteThickness[4]]]`

Comment: @Syed - Done. Thanks.

Comment: If you use `Sinc[x]` the exclusion isn't necessary.

Comment: Ah, making it thicker worked. I was also expecting a line as in a tangent exclusion, but of course the y value at x==0 is finite and visible. Sinc is also handy, being a predefined function.